# INSERT within Loop isn't working as I would expect (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, mysql, loops, insert

I am running a sentiment analysis against a table with 3 records (Fig 1). My  code (Fig 2) seems to work fine when I print the results to screen (Fig 3). For each of the 3 rows I return 3 values - a row ID, sentiment score and magnitude score . (9 results):

However, when I attempt to INSERT the same 9 values into a table (Fig 4) only the 3 values(from the first row) are inserted into my table.

I feel like this is really obvious, but I am perplexed as to what the issue is. Can anyone point out what is preventing the Insert working for all 3 iterations of the loop.

New to Coding.

**Fig 1.**

[image]

**Fig 2.**

```
import mysql.connector
from google.cloud import language
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='Blah', password='Blah',
                          host='Blah',
                          database='Blah')

cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)

Latest = ("SELECT ResID, TextResp FROM Response")

client = language.Client()

cursor.execute(Latest)
for row in cursor:
    document = client.document_from_text(row[1])
    sent_analysis = document.analyze_sentiment()
    sentiment = sent_analysis.sentiment
    annotations = document.annotate_text(include_sentiment=True, include_syntax=True, include_entities=True)
    ResID_ =row[0]
    PhraseSent_ = sentiment.score
    PhraseMag_ = sentiment.magnitude

    print(ResID_)
    print(PhraseSent_)
    print(PhraseMag_)

cnx.commit()
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

**Fig 3.**

[image: Fig 2]

**Fig 4. Loop with INSERT statement that isn't working as expected**

[image]

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: No error- the INSERT works, but only the first 3 values (1, -0.4, 2.2)  are inserted into the table (so the first iteration of the loop). I wanted (and expected) the all 9 values from Figure 3) to be inserted.

Comment: Ih Figure 3 you only get 3 values, but their are using 3 lines each one of them. You get values (1,-0.4,2.2), (2,-0.6,2.4) y (3,0.1,2.4). Yo don get 9 rows, just 3.

Comment: What does PhraseAnalysis look like when it's done?

Comment: @AndrewBone Just numeric values - here is what gets inserted into the  table (http://imgur.com/2MIXYMu). So only the first 3 values from figure 3. So the first value is the ResID_ which in this case is the row ID from the original table, The second value (PhraseSent_) is the sentiment (how positive the comment is and ranges from -1 to 1), the final value is the Magnitude (PhraseMag_) which is how "strong" the sentiment is. The key question is "Why aren't all 9 values from figure 3 inserted into the table?, rather than just 3".

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that the cursor that was being iterated through was only holding the first row from the table as opposed to all 3 rows. Changing

> for row in cursor:

to

> for row in cursor.fetchall():

resolved the issue